# Pass a value from a div to a textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a value that I am passing to a div in a bootstrap model using javascript code. I want to again use that value to filter data from MySQL database within a bootstrap modal but I have failed to pick the value from the div

Javascript Code that sends the vale to the div in Bootstrap

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#check_feedback').click(function() {
        $('#inquiry_id').html($('input[name=id]').val()); 
    })
</script>
```

Div code

```
<div id="inquiry_id"></div>
```

PHP code

```
$id = htmlspecialchars($_POST["inquiry_id"]);
```

this is the error that i see when i run this code
[The error that is see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqGTu.png)

Comment: please post your code properly.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. We need to see _all_ relative code so we can can see the context. We also need to know what currently happens when you run your code. For example, we have no idea how that PHP is related or how you even post `inquiry_id`.

Comment: The value is sent to the bootstrap div successfully but i can't get it into a PHP variable

Comment: That didn't add much more info. Please read the link I posted and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You didn't post the part of code that getting value in div

Comment: Share Your Codes

Comment: the javascript code is the one that takes the value to the div in the bootstrap

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I tried posting full code but i was limitted that's why i posted part of the code that i needed help with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

I have created an example, please change according to your needs.

```js
$('#check_feedback').click(function() {
   $('#textarea_id').val($('#inquiry_id').text()); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="inquiry_id">This content is wrap within div tag </div>
<div id="textbox_id"></div>
<textarea id="textarea_id"></textarea>
<button id="check_feedback">check feedback</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think my question I not well understood. I am able to display a value from a form to div in a bootstrap modal, but now the challenge is how to get the value from the div to a PHP variable or a textbox within a bootstrap modal. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MasabaJamesMoses - Your comment suggests that this didn't answer your question, but you accepted the answer anyway?

Comment: I finally figured out the solution through his guide though it was not a straightforward solution. I used a textarea instead of div and it worked for me the way I wanted that's why I accepted his answer. The reason was div does not accept the name attribute that can be posted while the textarea has the name attribute which accepted to be posted. Just thinking...